# ¿Cómo crear este método que agrega un objeto a un array?

Tags: javascript, array, class

Realizo este ejercicio en el cual debo implementar una clase `Empleado` en JavaScript.

> Crear una clase para construir objetos de tipo Empleado. El constructor debe recibir: nombre (string) , salario (integer), tareas (array de objetos), jefe (booleano - por defecto false). Esta función debe retonar la clase Persona.`

```javascript
function crearclassEmpleado() {
  class Empleado {
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe || false;

    }
  }
}
```

Hasta este punto todo bien, hasta que debo crear este método y agregar un objeto al array del empleado, no he podido crear el método que resuelva el test del ejercicio.

```javascript
addTarea(tarea, prioridad)
```

> El método addTarea recibe un string tarea y un entero prioridad y debe agregar un objeto `{tarea: tarea, prioridad: prioridad}` al arreglo de tareas del empleado. No debe retornar nada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes? Al ser un array basta con hacer un push del objeto tarea al array de `tareas`.

Comment: he implementando el metodo push y no me ha funcionado, al correr el test del ejercicio no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Para crear el método solo basta con utilizar el método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) del array `tareas`. Esto asumiendo que al momento de contruir la instancia de Empleado, pases un arrray y no otra cosa (no objeto, string, número, etc).

```js
class Empleado {
  constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.salario = salario;
    this.tareas = tareas;
    this.jefe = jefe || false;
  }

  addTarea(tarea, prioridad) {
    this.tareas.push({tarea, prioridad});
  }

  mostrarTareas() {
    return this.tareas;
  }
}

const empleado = new Empleado('Daniel Morales', 1000, [], false);

// Sin tareas previas, debido a que el contructor recibió []
console.log('Tareas iniciales: ', empleado.mostrarTareas());

// Agregar una nueva tarea
empleado.addTarea('Tarea 1', 1);

// Mostrar las tareas
console.log('Tareas agregadas', empleado.mostrarTareas());

// Agregar más tareas
for(let i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
  empleado.addTarea(`Tarea ${i}`, 1);
}

// Mostrar las tareas
console.log('Tareas agregadas', empleado.mostrarTareas());
```

Luego puedes llamar al método `addTarea()` y pasarle los argumentos requeridos (`tarea` y `prioridad`). Para mostrarlas simplemente retornas ese array, con el método `mostrarTareas()` por ejemplo.

Al ser un ejemplo debes recordar que puedes implementar las validaciones que sean necesarias para evitar que el usuario coloque un dato dinstinto de un array al momento de instanciar la clase. Por ejemplo, podrías aplicar el mismo principio que en `this.jefe`, si el usuario no proporciona un array de tareas, simplemente inicializarlo con un array vacío. Otra opción sería validar que se proporcione un array y lanzar un error en caso contrario. Hay muchas posibilidades.